# Aptana Studio (plug-in and standalone) is using system-wide Ruby instead of RVM Ruby

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rvm, aptana

I just installed Eclipse Juno with the Aptana plug-in. I imported a Rails app as a new project and the Rake pop-up menu (right click on the App Explorer) is empty the first time you hover the mouse pointer over it, and then disabled if you move the mouse off the Rake menu item. This happens with Aptana Studio (standalone), too.

I’m using RVM with Ruby 1.9.3 on a Linux Ubuntu machine. The same set-up (same project and RVM version) in OS X shows the Rake submenu properly. Have you experienced this? Is there any place (log file) that I may look into for troubleshooting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Experimenting a bit more I realized there’s something I’m not doing right with RVM. Aptana Terminal picks it up just right, but things like running the Rails server or the Rake submenu don’t work, because Aptana is using the system-wide Ruby installation and the corresponding gems are missing. If I run Aptana from the Gnome Terminal everything works fine. How can you set a local RVM to work with Aptana properly?

Comment: I’ve opened an issue at Aptana’s Jira here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7785